# Setting macOS keychain search list with user _www or daemon

Tags: ios, macos, security, keychain, codesign

We're using the codesign command on macOS for a CI system:

`codesign -v -f -s "identity" "file" --keychain "keychain_path"`

The keychain is created on the fly and contains a private key and a certificate.

This used to work great, but starting with **macOS Sierra (10.12)**, codesign does not include the custom keychain in its **keychain search list** anymore when looking up the certificate (accessing the private key works though).

Manually adding the keychain to the search list helps (at least as a common user):

`security list-keychains -s "previous_keychain_path" "custom_keychain_path"`

(where the previous search list has been fetched with "security list-keychains" first)

But this command is ignored when running **apache/httpd** as a **_www** or **daemon** user.

- What kind of permission is required for **_www** to modify the keychain search list temporarily?
- Is there another way of making **codesign** support the **--keychain** option as it did before Sierra?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your CI system is launched by LaunchDaemon.

You have to add

```
<key>SessionCreate</key>
<true/>
```

to LaunchDaemon <yourCIsystem>.plist file.

This modification allows CI system to modify the keychain search list.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, this is the best answer I can provide. I'm not an MacOS expert. The problem is the very few or no answers are available about this topic. I think some answer is better than nothing.

Comment: Thank you, this is great input! It's not solving the problem in the way I was thinking, but it's a very valuable hint.